# Vectorizing this non-unique-key operation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a non-unique original data called `test`. Using this input, I want to create an output vector together with a set of `rows` that get non-zero output, and the `data`, that contains their output.

```
import numpy as np

rows = np.array([3, 4])
test = np.array([1, 3, 3, 4, 5])
data = np.array([-1, 2])
```

My expected output is a vector of shape `test.shape`.

Each element in `output`:

- if `element` is in `rows` with index `i`, `output[i] = data[i]`
- otherwise, `output[i] = 0`

In other words, the following generates my output.

```
output = np.zeros(test.shape)
for i, val in enumerate(rows):
    output[test == val] = data[i]
```

Is there any way of vectorizing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach based upon [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
# Get sorted index positions
idx = np.searchsorted(rows, test)

# Set out-of-bounds(invalid ones) to some dummy index, say 0
idx[idx==len(rows)] = 0

# Get invalid mask array found out by indexing data array
# with those indices and looking for matches
invalid_mask = rows[idx] != test

# Get data indexed array as output and set invalid places with 0s
out = data[idx]
out[invalid_mask] = 0
```

Last couple of lines could have two alternatives, if you dig one-liners -

```
out = data[idx] * (rows[idx] == test) # skips using `invalid_mask`

out = np.where(invalid_mask, 0, data[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that only works if your `test` and `rows` consist of not too large integers (non negative as well but this can be relaxed if need be). But then it's fast:

```
>>> rows = np.array([3, 4])
>>> test = np.array([1, 3, 3, 4, 5])                                                                                        
>>> data = np.array([-1, 2])
>>> 
>>> limit = 1<<20
>>> assert all(a.dtype in map(np.dtype, np.sctypes['int']) for a in  (rows, test))
>>> assert np.all(rows>=0) and np.all(test>=0)
>>> mx = np.maximum(np.max(rows), np.max(test)) + 1
>>> assert mx <= limit
>>> lookup = np.empty((mx,), data.dtype)
>>> lookup[test] = 0
>>> lookup[rows] = data
>>> result = lookup[test]
>>> result
array([ 0, -1, -1,  2,  0])
```